# How to spell final "shhhh!" in gangster speak?

Tags: orthography, offensive

South Korean movies that deal with or involve gangsters, often feature gangter-speak, where every sentence ends with `-shh!`.

I always thought that stood for an expletive, `shibal`, is that correct?

In any case, how is this final sound spelt?

Comment: explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an interjection and spelled '[씨](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24454300)':

> 감탄사
>
> 마음에 차지 않거나 못마땅할 때 내는 소리. ‘시1’보다 센 느낌을 준다.
>
> 나만 빼놓고, 씨! 에이 씨! 싫어, 씨!

'씨발' is originally '씹할' and '씹' is vulgarism for woman's genitals or sex. '씨' is short for '씨발' and it is not considered as vulgar as '씨발'.

Whether to use '씨' or '씨발' makes a world of difference to movie producers because it will determine the rating of their movie in the same way using 'freaking' and 'fucking' does in English.

Comment: Isn't it "씹발?" (vulgarism for woman's pubic hair)

Comment: @Leftium Nope, it isn't.